# getting id from POST request

Tags: php, request

i'm watching a tutorial i'm watching a tutorials about CMS with OOP - PHP

on Control page :

```
public function Update()
{
    if(isset($_POST['updateArticle']))
    {
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

        //article data array
        //varaibles
        $title  = $_POST['title']; //title
        $content= $_POST['content']; //content
        $cat    = (int)$_POST['cat'];

        //Validation


        //data array

        $data = array(
            'title'   => $title,
            'content' => $content,
            'cid'     => $cat
        );

        //Insert
        if($this->articlesModel->Update($id,$data))
        {
            System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Article Updated');
            System::Get('tpl')->draw('success');
        }
        else
        {
            System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Error Updating article');
            System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');
        }


    }
    else
    {
        $id = 0 ; //init
        if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id'] > 0)
        {
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

            //Get article from db
            $article = $this->articlesModel->Get_By_Id($id);

            if(count($article)>0)
            {
                //categories
                $cats = $this->articlesCatsModel->Get();

             //article found
                System::Get('tpl')->assign($article);
                System::Get('tpl')->assign('cats',$cats);
                System::Get('tpl')->draw('updatearticle');

            }
            else
            {
                //article not found
                System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Article Not Found');
                System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //no id
            System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Ivalid ID');
            System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');
        }
    }


}
```

he get the `id`  from post request how !!!

we always take the id from url so GET Request

he did that because of this the source

source of the page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="updateArticle" value="Update Article" />
```

how can we take the id from post request !!

and if i changed it to GET request i get error

Comment: Change `$_GET["id"]` to `$_POST["id"]` or use JS to change `action="your-url?id=1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Form tag has a `method` attribute. This attribute defines whether the content will be sent using POST or GET.

Check the method of the `<form method=?>`.

Read: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: ok but  if i can get the id from <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="updateArticle" value="Update Article" />
why when i change it to $_POST['id] i get error .. i can know the id from url so post request too ! right !?

Comment: Yes but how inside http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp they type if id or something like we use GET request but here he uses POST i still don't know how  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
 because of this like he knew the id ? i need to know that

Comment: Ops you're right <form action="updatearticle.php" method="post" role="form"> but even if the method post i can get the id from which line :D because get request know id from the url ..but post request know the id from ??  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
 ?

Comment: yes but  $_POST['id'] can take it from the URL ?? or will take it from the source code ( <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" /> )

Comment: `$_POST['']` variables come from `<form method="POST">` fields (input texts, radio buttons, ...), where the key of the array (`$_POST['key']`) is the name of the field (`<input name="key" ... >`)

Comment: so in my example it comes from <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" /> ?

Comment: Yes, it comes from this hidden input

Comment: Finally ,, so i can get the id from GET request from url and POST request from the input